# How to check the length of an array passed as parameter in "CASE WHEN" condition

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
@Query("SELECT p " + "FROM product p " + "WHERE "
            + "( CASE WHEN ?1 <> '' THEN p.productFor = ?1 ELSE TRUE END OR p.productFor='Both' ) "
            + "AND p.productName LIKE %?2% " 
            + "AND CASE WHEN ?3 <> 0 THEN  p.productPrice >= ?3 ELSE TRUE END "
            + "AND CASE WHEN ?4 <> 0 THEN  p.productPrice <= ?4 ELSE TRUE END "
            + "AND CASE WHEN **CHECK THE LENGTH OF ?5 (for example: LENGTH(?5)>0)**  THEN  p.productColor IN ?5 ELSE TRUE END "
            + "ORDER BY productAddDate DESC   ")

Page<Product> findByProductForAndProductNameContainingAndProductPriceBetweenOrderByProductAddDateDesc(String gender,
        String name, double productMinPrice, double productMaxPrice, Set<String> colors, Pageable pageable);
```

Is there any function that I can use ? something like count, len, length, size ?? I've searched google and stackoverflow but found nothing! if not is there any other way to check if the colors SET is empty or not, if empty ignore the condition if it containts some elements, use " `THEN  p.productColor IN ?5` "

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: so how to do it ?

Comment: You'll need to get the length in Spring, not SQL. You can pass that length in as a query parameter.

Comment: ah alright thanks !<3